# php symfony ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED on openshift

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, openshift

I have a php 5.4 gear on openshift on which I can run my wordpress installation.

However, when I try to deploy my symfony app, I get `Content Encoding Error`, it seems like the html output is broken (not yet complete). I've tried modifying the .htaccess file as well as enable/disable output buffering and/or output compression setting on the apache's httpd.conf. Here is the output from curl:

```
$ curl --compress --raw -i http://webfront-interiorpediadev.rhcloud.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 01:52:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
X-Pingback: http://webfront-interiorpediadev.rhcloud.com/xmlrpc.php
Cache-Control: no-cache
x-pingback: http://webfront-interiorpediadev.rhcloud.com/xmlrpc.php
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-encoding: gzip
accept-ranges: none
Content-Length: 20
X-Debug-Token: a9e740
X-Debug-Token-Link: /_profiler/a9e740
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=gtarr5ls6tdcejdelrjrffr9p6; path=/
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=jtebjs0ihrdqhvo6f2gicq0rp0; path=/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
```

I really have no idea why I do not receive the entire html output, `Content-Length` header output looks suspiciously small, but google search and php/apache documentation says that `Content-Length` header will not be reliable for gzip output.

I've been debugging this thingy for quite some time now and really run out of idea to tackle it. The app coding is fine, as I have deployed the exact same copy on my localhost during development. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Here is the `phpinfo()` output for my apache configuration on openshift:

[phpinfo on openshift](http://webfront-interiorpediadev.rhcloud.com/others/phpinfo_openshift.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deploy a Symfony app to Openshift is:

1. Be sure you have a Symfony2 app working well in localhost (dev and prod)
2. Your proyect have to be using git.
3. Your .gitignore file is ignoring vendors, cache, bootstrap, logs, composer etc.
4. You have committed every pending change.
5. You need an openshift gear using PHP 5.4 and a cartridge of MySql 5.5
6. You need rhc to be installed and configured
7. Config your gear to public a branch called `release`: `rhc app-configure --deployment-branch release -a <app-name>`
8. Create a new php file that will give MySQL access to your app:

---

```
<?php
# app/config/params.php
if (getEnv("OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME")!='') {
    $container->setParameter('database_host', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"));
    $container->setParameter('database_port', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"));
    $container->setParameter('database_name', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME"));
    $container->setParameter('database_user', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
    $container->setParameter('database_password', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));
}?>
```

*This will tell the app that if is openshift environment it needs to load different user an database*

9. Import this file (params.php) to your app/config/config.yml file:

---

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: params.php }
...
```

10. Commit your changes.
11. Create a new branch that will push your changes to Openshift: `git checkout -b release`
12. Add your remote repository from openshift: `git remote add openshift -f <youropenshiftrepository.git>`
13. Merge the differences between both repositories `git merge openshift/master -s recursive -X ours`
14. Create a 'deploy' file (the one executed in openshift after you push your app) in your new folder "/.openshift/action-hooks" (Created when you added your openshift repository):

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# Symfony deploy
export COMPOSER_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.composer"

if [ ! -f "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar" ]; then
    curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
else
    php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar self-update
fi

unset GIT_DIR 
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/
php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar install

php $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/app/console cache:clear --env=dev

chmod -R 0777 $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/app/cache
chmod -R 0777 $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/app/logs

rm -r $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php
ln -s $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/web $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php

rm -r $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php
ln -s $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/web $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php

php $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

15. Give this file permissions to be executed. In windows: `git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy` In Linux and Mac: `chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy`
16. Add your new file to the git project and make the commit.
17. Push to openshift: `git push openshift HEAD`
18. Your console will show you every step it is working on.
19. Come back to your master branch. `git checkout master`
20. Then you can keep working normaly on your project, commit your changes and move to `release` branch to deploy your new changes: `git checkout release` `git merge master` `git push openshift HEAD` `git checkout master`

And that's how I work with Symfony and Openshift. (These instructions are a mix from many ways I read and I imporved with some changes. It works very well for every app I've made.

Comment: Thanks! That's one nice workflow! I'm still new to openshift and symfony so my workflow is still a mess. I'll adopt your input :)

Btw, have you ever encountered the content decoding failed? It seems like the output buffering failed and I didn't get the full output.. Openshift is processing the request very slowly though..

Comment: I thought if you tried this way to deploy your app, the content decoding could works fine as it works in localhost. Most of my issues deploying apps started working when I adopted the deploy file. Maybe you can run those instructions direct from your console with shell access to your app.